# How to display an image inside an overflowing stack, inside a container that has a Clipper ( ClipPath() )?

Tags: flutter, flutter-clippath

I'm not sure if I'm making sense but essentially, I want to have a full-sized image inside a container that has a clipper ( `ClipPath()` ). The image needs to overflow past both clippers.
Here is what I was trying to achieve:

| Image of a woman inside a custom container whilst overflowing | My output/attempt of putting an overflowing image inside a custom clipper contanier |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

Unfortunately, my method does not work as i get this error message:

> Assertion failed: ..\…\widgets\basic.dart:920
>
> clipBehavior != Clip.none
>
> is not true

**This is my code**

```
Stack(
  children: [
    Positioned(
      bottom: size.height * .2,
      right: size.width * .1,
      child: ClipPath(
        clipBehavior: Clip.none,
        clipper: ContactFullTriangleClipper(),
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.teal,
          width: size.width * .3,
          height: size.height * .4,
          child: Stack(
            clipBehavior: Clip.none,
            children: [
              Positioned(
                bottom: 0,
                child: Image.asset('/images/me/bottom.png',
                  height: size.height * .5,
                  fit: BoxFit.fitHeight),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

The error appears when both `Stack`'s and `ClipPaths`'s `clipBehavior` property is set to `Clip.none`. Please help, thanks!

Comment: you can put the image over the background element image